# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

Tags: ssl, encryption, websphere, sslhandshakeexception

1. I am trying to install IHS certs in Websphere Application Server 8.5
   and after I install the IHS WebServer certs I am getting
   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common.
2. I did not even touch the application server or go into the Cell Level 
   but both the IHS and the app server are on the same box.
3. Please help me resolve this and point out where and why is the root
   cause for all this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but your question is very broad and we can not answer your question in your current form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Websphere but you can get this kind of error if the server side has no certificates configured and thus falls back to the ADH ciphers (anonymous authentication). These ciphers are usually not supported by the clients, at least not by default and thus you get "no shared ciphers". Just a guess because of lack of more information in the question.